# Trying to get JSON with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying to get the JSON with that example from [www.w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_getjson)

I just edit de url JSON to "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js"

I copied that into my desktop index.html and it doesn't works in local machine. I tried upload it to my web and it doesnt works... Can you help me please?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [Don't use w3schools](http://www.w3fools.com/). Go straight to the [source](http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/) instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery AJAX cross domain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain)

Answer (score 2):

you are trying to send Cross-Origin Request

Install [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) and check in [firebug](https://getfirebug.com/) console you will see this error message

"Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS."

Read more in this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11513738/1868660)

Answer (score 1):

I have uploaded the running code on JSfiddle. Take a look at the [link](http://jsfiddle.net/ammad205/PaaHm/).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.getJSON("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/developer-calendar@google.com/public/full?alt=json",function(result){
      $.each(result, function(i, field){
        $("div").append(field + " ");
      });
    });
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Get JSON data</button>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See your browser console :

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/demo_ajax_json.js. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

You can not directly request the file, you are not allowed

One solution could be to use php, and call the php file from js with ajax